# Spring-LDAP - Password Compare How-to Update Failed Password Attempts

Tags: java, spring, ldap, spring-ldap

Using ApacheDS 2.0.0, the pertinent portion of the config is:

```
dn: ads-pwdId=default,ou=passwordPolicies,ads-interceptorId=authenticationInterceptor,ou=interceptors,ads-directoryServiceId=default,ou=config
ads-pwdminlength: 5
ads-pwdinhistory: 5
ads-pwdid: default
ads-pwdcheckquality: 1
ads-pwdlockout: TRUE
ads-pwdlockoutduration: 0
ads-pwdvalidator: org.apache.directory.server.core.api.authn.ppolicy.DefaultPasswordValidator
ads-pwdmaxfailure: 5
ads-pwdattribute: userPassword
ads-pwdfailurecountinterval: 30
entryParentId: 0889249e-fc0d-44ec-9df6-af21e46b3dac
ads-enabled: TRUE
objectclass: ads-passwordPolicy
objectclass: ads-base
objectclass: top
entryuuid: 22d39b05-7219-471f-9ca5-a9b12aff7a9e
ads-pwdgraceauthnlimit: 5
modifytimestamp: 20150409194653.529Z
entrycsn: 20150409194653.530000Z#000000#001#000000
ads-pwdexpirewarning: 600
modifiersname: 0.9.2342.19200300.100.1.1=admin,2.5.4.11=system
```

and then in Spring-LDAP 3.2.5 / Security, I use the following authentication manager configuration:

```
<authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
    <ldap-authentication-provider
        user-context-mapper-ref="detailsMapper"
        user-dn-pattern="uid={0},ou=people" user-search-filter="(uid={0})"
        group-search-base="ou=groups" group-search-filter="member={0}">
        <password-compare />
    </ldap-authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>
```

I probably misunderstand the boundaries around "password-compare" but when I removed that element the LDAP seemed to maintain the "pwdFailureTime" password failures.  With "password-compare" element that is lost so accounts are not being locked for multiple password failures.

Any thoughts on what I'm missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use `password-compare` you aren't doing a bind to LDAP as the user, with his password, as LDAP is supposed to be used, so LDAP is never seeing the failed login attempt.

Instead, Spring extracts the password from the user entry, acting as an LDAP admin, and compares the password itself.

You should not use this option. It is contrary to the intent of the design of LDAP.

Comment: Ok, thank you ... but then why have it?  (What is its correct purpose?)

Comment: It doesn't have a correct purpose. It's a misfeature.

Comment: Well that explains why its confusing the hell out of me.. Thank you!